# Qt QJsonModel isn't working at end of network request

Tags: c++, json, qt, treeview

So, after I make my QJsonModel, load the data, and set the treeView model, it will load the data normally into the treeView. Although, when I do this after a network request has been finished (`serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)`), it just doesn't woek. I can qDebug the Json data that is passed, but when it comes down to the Json loading and the model setting. It just fails to finish. Also, for some reason it won't set the Json from the network request, but if I just set it to set the json from a separate button, the json get added successfully. So that means that the Json is formatted correctly. The QJsonModel & QJsonItem are external classes not provided with Qt, that located [here](https://github.com/dridk/QJsonmodel).
Here is my code:

Mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QItemSelection>
#include <QFile>
#include <QFileInfo>
#include <QList>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QTreeWidgetItem>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include "qjsonmodel.h"
#include <QClipboard>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    void setJson(QString json);
    void getPlaylistList(QString accessToken);
    QString disableStreams();
    void appendEditValues(int currentRow);
    void addVectorItems();
    void streamCheck();

    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_radioButtonNoStream_clicked()
    {
        streamCheck();
    }

    void on_radioButtonTwitchStream_clicked()
    {
        streamCheck();
    }

    void on_radioButtonYTStream_clicked()
    {
        streamCheck();
    }

    void on_pushButtonAddVid_clicked();

    void on_pushButtonApplyAddVid_clicked();

    void on_pushButtonDeleteSelection_clicked();

    void on_pushButtonApplyAll_clicked();

public slots:
    void serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply* reply);

    void connectAPI(QString code);

signals:
    void authenticate(QString accessCode);

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "authdialog.h"
#include <qDebug>
#include <QVector>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QFile>
#include <QUrlQuery>

int val = 0;
int selected;

QVector<QString> vidTitles;
QVector<QString> vidUrls;
QVector<int> vidNumber;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    streamCheck();
    ui->groupBoxEditVideo->setEnabled(false);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(authenticate(QString)), SLOT(connectAPI(QString)));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::streamCheck()
{
    if (ui->radioButtonNoStream->isChecked())
    {
        ui->groupBoxStreamSetup->setEnabled(false);
        ui->groupBoxStreamSetup->setTitle("No Stream Selected!");
    }
    else if (ui->radioButtonTwitchStream->isChecked())
    {
        ui->groupBoxStreamSetup->setEnabled(true);
        ui->groupBoxStreamSetup->setTitle("Twitch Setup");
    }
    else if (ui->radioButtonYTStream->isChecked())
    {
        ui->groupBoxStreamSetup->setEnabled(true);
        ui->groupBoxStreamSetup->setTitle("YouTube Stream Setup");
    }
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonAddVid_clicked()
{
    AuthDialog *auth = new AuthDialog(this);
    auth->setModal(true);
    auth->exec();
    delete auth;
}

void MainWindow::setJson(QString json)
{
    qDebug() << json;
    QJsonModel * model = new QJsonModel;
    model->loadJson(json.toUtf8());
    ui->treeView->setModel(model);
    delete model;
}

void MainWindow::getPlaylistList(QString accessToken)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    //
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&forMine=true&order=viewCount&type=video&access_token=" + accessToken));
    networkManager->get(request);
}

QString MainWindow::disableStreams()
{
    QString line = "";
    QString test = "";
    QFile file;
    file.setFileName("C:/WampStack/apache2/htdocs/index.html");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    QTextStream in(&file);

    while(!in.atEnd())
    {
        line += in.readAll();
    }
    if (line.contains("<!--t-->") && !line.contains("<!--y-->"))
    {
        //Twitch Stream is on, must turn it off
        test = line.replace("<!--t-->", "<!--t");
        test = test.replace("><!--tt-->", ">tt-->");
        return test;
    }
    else if (line.contains("<!--y-->") && !line.contains("<!--t-->"))
    {
        //YouTube Stream is on, must turn it off
        test = line.replace("<!--y-->", "<!--y");
        test = test.replace("><!--yy-->", ">yy-->");
        return test;
    }
    else if (line.contains("<!--y-->") && line.contains("<!--t-->"))
    {
        test = line.replace("<!--y-->", "<!--y");
        test = test.replace("><!--yy-->", ">yy-->");
        test = test.replace("<!--t-->", "<!--t");
        test = test.replace("><!--tt-->", ">tt-->");
        return test;
    }
    else
    {
        return line;
    }
    file.close();
    return line;
}

void MainWindow::connectAPI(QString code)
{
    QNetworkAccessManager *networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    connect(networkManager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    QUrlQuery postData;
    postData.addQueryItem("code", code);
    postData.addQueryItem("client_id", "CLIENT-ID");
    postData.addQueryItem("client_secret", "CLIENT-SECRET");
    postData.addQueryItem("redirect_uri", "REDIRECT-URI");
    postData.addQueryItem("grant_type", "authorization_code");
    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"));
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    networkManager->post(request, postData.toString(QUrl::FullyEncoded).toUtf8());
}

void MainWindow::appendEditValues(int currentRow)
{

}

void MainWindow::addVectorItems()
{

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonApplyAddVid_clicked()
{

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonDeleteSelection_clicked()
{
    QMessageBox::StandardButton reply;
    reply = QMessageBox::question(this, "Are you sure?", "Do you want to permanently delete this entry?", QMessageBox::Yes|QMessageBox::No);
    if (reply == QMessageBox::Yes)
    {



    }
    addVectorItems();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonApplyAll_clicked()
{
    QString line = disableStreams();
    QFile::remove("C:/WampStack/apache2/htdocs/index.html");
    QFile file;
    file.setFileName("C:/WampStack/apache2/htdocs/index.html");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite);
    //Start code for streaming
    if (ui->radioButtonTwitchStream->isChecked() && line.contains("<!--t") && line.contains(">tt-->") && !line.contains("<!--t-->") && !line.contains("<!--tt-->"))
    {
        QString test = line.replace("<!--t", "<!--t-->");
        test = line.replace(">tt-->", "><!--tt-->");
        QTextStream stream( &file );
        stream << test;
    }
    else if (ui->radioButtonYTStream->isChecked() && line.contains("<!--y") && line.contains(">yy-->") && !line.contains("<!--y-->") && !line.contains("<!--yy-->"))
    {
        QString test = line.replace("<!--y", "<!--y-->");
        test = test.replace(">yy-->", "><!--yy-->");
        QTextStream stream( &file );
        stream << test;
    }
    else if (ui->radioButtonNoStream->isChecked())
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        stream << line;
    }
    //End code for streaming
    file.close();
}

void MainWindow::serviceRequestFinished(QNetworkReply* reply)
{
    QByteArray json = reply->readAll();
    QString output = QString::fromUtf8(json);
    QJsonDocument settdoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(output.toUtf8());
    QJsonObject sett2 = settdoc.object();
    if (val == 0)
    {

        val++;
        getPlaylistList(sett2.value(QString("access_token")).toString());
    }
    else if (val == 1)
    {
        setJson(output.toUtf8());
    }

}
```

Main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You're definitely leaking memory in 'setJson' as  the previous model is never deleted!

Comment: @Flopp Lol. Just fixed it in my code, I'll update the post as well.

Answer (score 0):

QJsonModel only works if the the JSON's root element is an object (see the [bug report on github.com](https://github.com/dridk/QJsonmodel/issues/2)). I guess your JSON's root is an array.

Comment: Yes, that is true, but if you read the article in it's entirety. He states that he's fixed this bug.

Comment: Go read my last edit. The formatting is correct, but it just 'doesn't' call. I have no idea and I am stumped.